# AssemblyOS questions

Tags: assembly, operating-system

So, I am making an OS in Assembly for fun and learning. I have a few questions however. First of all, I want my OS to make use of all the cores/threads it can.  In Python, you just `import multiprocessing` and then use a pool/threads script to make use of a set number of cores. I want the user to be prompted to enter the number of cores in their system (or it is automatically detected) and then it is stored away in a text file or something like that, so that the next time you boot the OS reads the text file and says, "Hey, he has four cores. Use them." Can I achieve this by using Assembly to run a python program, or just pure Assembly? If so, please tell me how.
Secondly, how do I get keyboard input in Assembly? In python, it is `a=raw_input("enter text here")` but I don't know how to in Assembly. I need to know because my OS is like a great big terminal. Thanks, and sorry if this is too long. I'm new to the site and have a bunch of questions.

Comment: You do know *some* language besides Python, right? Because Python doesn't come anywhere close to the level of detail that your assembly code will have to. (You can't cheat by running Python either, cause you'd need an OS that already supports Python.) And if you don't even know how to get input in assembly yet, you're nowhere near the level of knowledge you'd need to actually make an OS that works at all, let alone one built for SMP.

Comment: I know Wolfram (I learned the online version of that during school for one of my classes), Python (2.7 or something like that), and I am trying to use the OS project to learn Assembly by following tutorials and then changing stuff as I learn. And as for the input in assembly, I am trying to figure it out; why else would I have made a post about it? Everybody's gotta start somewhere.

Comment: https://github.com/tatimmer/tatOS/tree/master/usb I found this and https://github.com/lizh0019/Keyboard-driver-assembly-200402/blob/master/KB.ASM on GitHub. Would these work? I mean, its different than making the driver myself, but, whatever works...

Comment: The tatOS stuff should be useful. The standalone keyboard driver example (and the existing answer) is 16-bit, which these days is basically worthless outside of a boot loader, and is not going to play well with the multi-core stuff you want to play with.

Comment: I suspect that you are in trouble.  You need to know about interrupts and drivers.  I don't think you understand the scope of what you are considering, because it's massive:(

Comment: Your OS will use all cores for what? (usually you don't want an OS to use any core at all, if it runs as close as possible to 0% CPU usage, that's the best case scenario). Leave the cores to the user of the OS. But that means your kernel will have to work in multi-threaded way, actually surviving simultaneous activity on several cores, which itself takes usually some weeks or months of programming theory study and practice, to even get some idea what you have to do and how and how to design architecture of your OS to allow such stunt. And it goes in similar way with rest of your questions...

Comment: This is true.__

Comment: If you are asking these questions you are not ready to write an operating system, start with something simpler and work your way up.  I also highly recommend that you avoid using x86 for this initial education.  Since you didnt specify the processor nor assembler it is hard to even begin to help here.

Comment: BTW if you are writing the operating system then YOU control the threads via the rules and design of that processor which you learn by reading.  99% of what you are trying to do here has nothing to do with assembly language, the programming is the easy part, whatever language you choose (ideally C with some assembly as required, but you can make your life more painful if you wish).

Comment: also note assembly language or lets say machine code is the only language that can do everything the hardware can do, other languages have restrictions.  so if it can be done then yes of course it can be done in assembly language.  adding python to your operating system is a major project you have to have the operating system first then build the python vm.  avoid any discussions about python until you have a functioning operating system.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I get keyboard input in Assembly?

You can use the BIOS keyboard API for input of a single key.

```
mov ah, 00h  ;BIOS.GetKey
int 16h      ; -> AL is ASCII, AH is scancode
```

> Can I achieve this by using Assembly to run a python program, or just pure Assembly?

If you're making an OS **in Assembly** (for fun and learning), then all the things you ask about are possible from writing assembly code.

As an example displaying a prompt:

```
    cld
    mov  si, msg
    mov  bx, 0007h  ; Display page 0 and Color WhiteOnBlack
    jmp  .b
.a: mov  ah, 0Eh    ; BIOS.Teletype
    int  10h
.b: lodsb
    test al, al
    jnz  .a
    ...
msg: db 'How many cores?',0
```

Reading and writing files requires you to develop a filesystem of your own, or simpler, use the filesystem that's already on the disk (like Fat16) from the existing OS.

Comment: I doubt if you are writing an OS in this day an age that one would find yourself doing it from real mode/using the BIOS. Usually people undertaking real OS development would be interfacing with the hardware directly. That may come in the form (on modern hardware) of interfacing with emulated PS2/mouse hardware  (provided by SMM) or writing USB drivers and then creating USB Keyboard/USB Mouse drivers.

Comment: you use real mode bios/etc calls to get your operating system launched, then you can continue to try to thunk down to this or take over.